# How can the Chrome browser treat the numpad keys as arrow keys when the xkb option numpad (mac) is active?

Tags: chrome, xkb

I'm using the Num Lock key as meta key and have set the numpad keys permanently (as if Num Lock was active all the time). Many desktop apps (`konsole`, the Atom editor, LibreOffice) and even the login screen treat the keys as number keys, but the Chrome browser apparently thinks they were arrow keys, so that I can't use the numpad when working with Chrome (version 86.0).

Here is my complete xkbmap and OS version (OpenSuSE Leap 15.1):

```bsh
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  setxkbmap -verbose 10        
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc102
layout:     de
variant:    pl
options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,compose:sclk,altwin:meta_win,lv3:ralt_switch,numpad:mac
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwertz)
types:      complete+numpad(mac)
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+de(pl)+inet(evdev)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)+altwin(meta_win)+level3(ralt_switch)+compose(sclk)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)
geometry:   pc(pc102)

╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  uname -a
Linux epica 4.12.14-lp151.28.71-default #1 SMP Thu Oct 8 12:40:48 UTC 2020 (dda1832) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`xev` seems to treat the numpad keys correctly:

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x7800001,
    root 0x561, subw 0x0, time 5259457, (-134,654), root:(702,683),
    state 0x0, keycode 90 (keysym 0xffb0, KP_0), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (30) "0"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (30) "0"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x7800001,
    root 0x561, subw 0x0, time 5259617, (-134,654), root:(702,683),
    state 0x0, keycode 90 (keysym 0xffb0, KP_0), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (30) "0"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x7800001,
    root 0x561, subw 0x0, time 5260449, (-134,654), root:(702,683),
    state 0x0, keycode 87 (keysym 0xffb1, KP_1), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (31) "1"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (31) "1"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x7800001,
    root 0x561, subw 0x0, time 5260594, (-134,654), root:(702,683),
    state 0x0, keycode 87 (keysym 0xffb1, KP_1), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (31) "1"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x7800001,
    root 0x561, subw 0x0, time 5260922, (-134,654), root:(702,683),
    state 0x0, keycode 88 (keysym 0xffb2, KP_2), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (32) "2"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (32) "2"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x7800001,
    root 0x561, subw 0x0, time 5261058, (-134,654), root:(702,683),
    state 0x0, keycode 88 (keysym 0xffb2, KP_2), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (32) "2"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x7800001,
    root 0x561, subw 0x0, time 5261497, (-134,654), root:(702,683),
    state 0x0, keycode 89 (keysym 0xffb3, KP_3), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (33) "3"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (33) "3"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x7800001,
    root 0x561, subw 0x0, time 5261658, (-134,654), root:(702,683),
    state 0x0, keycode 89 (keysym 0xffb3, KP_3), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (33) "3"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

So: Why does Chrome simply ignore the `numpad (mac)` setting in the `xkb` config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after a minor Chrome update I received, the numpad now works with the browser. Save for a hint that Chrome for Unix might rely on **scancodes** directly than on X.org keycodes (conceptual flaw?), I found nothing about this matter.

Comment: I found my way here because this is driving me insane. On multiple Linux distros the Google Chrome web browser fails to treat the num-pad as numerics even when numlock is on and every other program does the right thing. No solution.